# Как отправить в JSP отправить текст запроса c выбранной строкой из выпадающего списка?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

У меня есть форма что-то вроде такой:

```
<form action="myAction/" method="post">
    <p><select  size="3" multiple name="$hero">
        <option disabled>Выберитеoption>
        <option value="1">Один/option>
        <option value="2">Два</option>
        <option value="3">Три</option>
        <option value="4">Четыре</option>
    </select></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Как мне добавить к action/ выбранную строку что бы получилось например action="myAction/2" ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете с помощью JavaScript изменять `action` при выборе значения из списка.

Если же на самом деле вы хотите при разных опциях получать управление в разных контроллерах, то я советую использовать `params="myParam=myValue"` (см. документацию: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers)